# How to improve a bandpass filter design

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, band-pass

I want to design an active RC bandpass filter to filter out frequencies between 5MHz to 10MHz for a radiation detection circuit. I am using LTspice for the circuit simulation.

I have used a cascade connection of a high pass filter, a low pass filter and an op-amp in non inverting configuration as an amplifier.

[image]

I was unable to decide which op-amp to use.

I initially used an LT1012 but the cutoff frequency for its open-loop gain was lower than 10MHz so I looked through some datasheets and found the LT1800 which seems to be better for the frequency range I am designing the filter for.

The Bode magnitude plot for the circuit is:

[image: Bode plot]

- If I want to change the op-amp again what criteria should I look for while choosing the op-amp?
- How can I improve my design?
- What can be done to make the ouput plot look more like an ideal bandpass filter?

I am absolutely new to filter design.

Comment: The first thing you want to do is to swap R1 and R4.  As it stands, you've got your high and low frequencies mixed up. Actually, you want to put your lowpass section first, with the proper component values, and your highpass last.

Comment: Please define better specs for gain and BW

Comment: delete U2 and U3, only U1 is doing anything worthwhile. U1 is already high Z input and low Z output.

Comment: This filter's fractional bandwidth is about 0.7. So it should ***not*** be designed as a combination of two filters, one low-pass and one high-pass, but instead as a single bandpass filter design. This is because the responses of the stages in a multi-stage filter increasingly interact in your case and should be not considered separately. It's not a hard-line, but a rule of thumb I use. I go to separate designs when the fractional bandwidth is at least 0.8 and usually > 1.0.

Comment: Filters design are not an trivial and easy task. As we don't know your background in electronic knowledge i'm assuming your not a total beginner. With that being said, i would suggest you take a look and time to see/study the Sallen Key topology first so that you have a nice and applicable starting point.

Comment: Ameya, if you haven't gotten the point yet, getting to a good design isn't resolved by telling you how to go about *"choosing the op-amp." That's putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: Ameya, first you should decide on these things (see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band-pass_filter) for details): what is the useful (passband) bandwidth, what is the center frequency, what is the stopband bandwidth, what attenuation to have in the passband and whether it can tolerate ripple, or not, what attenuation in the stopband and whether it can tolerate ripple or not, what is the maximum order that you can physically make? There are other things, but these should be from the start.